# Find a function $g$ such that $(1*g)(t)=t^{-1/2}$.

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, convolution, inverse-laplace

Is there some function $g: (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$(1*g)(t)=t^{-1/2}$$
for all $t>0$? Here the sign $*$ represents the convolution. I tried apply the Laplace transform both site of the equality, but i arrive that
$$g(t)=[\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\lambda^{\frac{1}{2}})](t)$$
so I can't develop it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: $$(1*g)(t)=\int_0^t g(s)ds=t^{-1/2}$$
For any smooth function $g(s)$ at $t\to0\,$ LHS $\to0$ and RHS $\to\infty$, so such smooth function does not exist.

Comment: @Svyatoslav it dont need to be smooth. May be a $L^1_{loc}$ function for example.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138137/does-the-inverse-laplace-transform-of-the-square-root-exist

Comment: I think that the idea is do not use laplace transform.

Comment: $g$ exists as a distribution. If
$$(t_+^{-3/2}, \phi) =
\int_{\mathbb R^+} \frac {\phi(t) - \phi(0)} {t^{3/2}} dt,$$
then $\mathcal L[t_+^{-3/2}](s) = -2 \sqrt {\pi s}$ and $H * (-t_+^{-3/2}/2) = H(t)/\sqrt t$ (the convolution is always well-defined for distributions with supports bounded on the same side).

Comment: @Maxim I do not understant how define a laplace transform of a distribution. For example, what wold be $\int_0^\infty e^{-t\lambda} (t_+^{-3/2})dt$?